# How to make unit interval on both axes to have equal lengths visually in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I want to make a plot in which unit interval on both axes to have equal lengths visually. i.e. I want (1,1) and (0,0) to make a square rather than an elongated rectangle.

I could not find the option to make it possible for the following simple case:

`ListLinePlot[{{{0, 0}, {1, -1}, {2, -2}, {3, -1}, {4, -2}, {5, -3}, {6, -4}, {7,
-3}, {8, -2}, {9, -1}}}]`

Thank you for your help.

**Edit**

More generally, how to adjust the ratio of the unit interval on x-axis to that on y-axis? `AspectRatio` option does not seem to directly correlate with it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You want: `AspectRatio -> Automatic`.

---

Example of the requested generalization:

```
p = Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}];
range = First /@ Differences /@ (PlotRange /. Options[p]);
target = 1/2;(* 1 y == 2 x *)
Show[p, 
 AspectRatio -> (Last[range]/First[range]/target)]
```

(`Plot` by default will include an explicit plot range, so we can use `Options`, as long as we don't set something like `PlotRange->All`.)

Comment: @Brett, oh, I literally tried `AspectRatio -> 1` before I asked this question!

Comment: Curiously, the default is `AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio` and not `Automatic`

Comment: @belisarius `AspectRatio -> Automatic` should be used with care. Consider: `ListPlot[100 Range[5], AspectRatio -> Automatic]`

Comment: @Brett What I tried to imply is that the "expected" default value is Automatic. Not that the Automatic value is the better one.

Comment: exactly as I "expected" initially. :)

Comment: Off the top of my head, `ParametricPlot` and `ParametricPlot3D` are the only functions to use the `Automatic` settings for `AspectRatio` and `BoxRatios`, respectively.  (`RevolutionPlot3D` also uses `BoxRatios->Automatic`, but in a different way that doesn't result in such extreme plots.)

Comment: @Brett: what if I want the length of unit interval on x-axis is twice of that on y-axis, or for that matter, any ratio? Is there any parameter to adjust?

Comment: For that, I think you need to additionally know what the plot range is, and compute the aspect ratio taking that into account.

Comment: @Brett, sorry that I am still bugging here. An example on how to do that would be greatly appreciated. :)